# Inconsistent rounding in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, operator-precedence

I calculated an amount of money in Oracle DB 10g (10.2.0.4.0 64bit), but I can't understand how some of the numbers are calculated

**Set one**

```
10000 * (1 / 30) = 333.333*
15600 * (8 / 15) = 8319.999*
```

**Set two**

```
7800 * (1 / 30) = 260*
23400 * (5 / 6) = 19500*
```

Based on set one I expected the set two calculations to result in 259.9 and 19499.9, unlike the actual results.

If 260 and 19500 are the correct results for set two I would have thought that that `15600 * (8 / 15)` should result in 8320.

I was doing this in SQL, for instance:

```
select 15600 * (8 / 15) from dual
```

Comment: Your query tool/client may be rounding the results.  How are you running these queries?

Comment: The client wouldn't add additional decimal places though @OldProgrammer

Comment: Interesting if you do 15600 * 8 / 15 you get 8320.  Mathematically the ()'s shouldn't matter but they appear to be causing some rounding within the engine. `Select 15600*8/15, 15600*(8/15) from dual;` using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: @OldProgrammer
I used Object Browser(http://www.sint.co.jp/products/siob/ob/index.html, this site is japanese only). Another I tried  by C# application, but the results are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're seeing this then it would appear to be a bug in 10g:

It's fine in 12c

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where banner like 'Oracle%';

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select 15600 * (8 / 15)  from dual;

15600*(8/15)
------------
        8320
```

and in 11.2

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where banner like 'Oracle%';

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select 15600 * (8 / 15)  from dual;

15600*(8/15)
------------
        8320

SQL>
```

[Oracle's operator order of precendence](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators001.htm#SQLRF51153) places addition and subtraction ahead of multiplication and division. So, I would expect these to resolve as follows:

```
10000 x (1 / 30) = 10000 x 0.03333* = 333.333*
15600 x (8 / 15) = 15600 x 0.5333* = 8320
7800 x (1 / 30) = 7800 x 0.03333* = 260
23400 x (5 / 6) = 23400 x 0.833333* = 19500
```

I disagree with [OldProgrammers' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744879/inconsistent-rounding-in-oracle/31746526#comment51426430_31744879) as the implication of the results from 11.2 and 12 is that Oracle 10 is not "rounding" up correctly, if the client was at fault I would be expecting less rounding not more.

Comment: Thank you for you comment and tried in 12c and 11.2. I think It would be the bug in 10g too.